# Returning object to ajax Web Service method

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services

I can't return javascript object to web method thru ajax call like below:

```
var person = {"FirstName":"Foo","LastName":"Bar"};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: person,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    onSuccess: function () { alert('Success!'); },
    onError: function () { alert('Error'); }
});
```

Invalid JSON primitive is thrown with the method above.
I'd to resort to string manipulation like this:

```
var person = {"FirstName":"Foo","LastName":"Bar"};
var json = '{person:' + JSON.stringify(person) + '}';

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: json,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    onSuccess: function () { alert('Success!'); },
    onError: function () { alert('Error'); }
});
```

Now, this is working fine, i can get away with this solution, but life is hard, we don't want harder! If there's a way to pass the object directly i'd love to hear it ;)

Comment: What type of error do you have?First an example works fine.

Comment: @Oyeme: it throws "Invalid JSON primitive:FirstName blahh".. It needs a Person wrapper to reconstruct the object, hence the string manipulation.. It worked on your machine??

Comment: Yes,it works.You have corrected JSON format {"FirstName":"Foo","LastName":"Bar"};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var json = '{person:' + JSON.stringify(person) + '}';

did the job :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason for that is likely that this:

```
data: person
```

Actually sends this:

```
FirstName=Foo&LastName=Bar
```

because jQuery breaks down that object into a POST-friendly key/value set. The reason you second version works is because it's actually sending a real JSON string. If you were to do this:

```
data: JSON.stringify(person)
```

That would likely work.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that jQuery breaks down the object to key/value set! But data: JSON.stringify(person) still don't work. It now throws "Cannot convert object to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary[System.String.System.Object]'"